# Is it possible to keep everything still working when I place a python class to somewhere else, without editing the caller and callee?

Tags: python

I'm starting to use Python for some real things and quickly realized that anything related to importing from another folder is a mess. I would like to know whether I can get something like "Project Dependencies" in other IDEs that link my own projects together, or I can get a library to do that for me, like what I can get from many application frameworks.

Let's say that we have a project which looks like this:

```
{root}
-- foo
---- foo.py
------class foo()
-- bar
---- bar.py
------class bar()
```

You get to use tricky import commands like modifying `sys.path` , `PYTHONPATH` or use relative lookups which doesn't work anymore when `class bar` is moved somewhere else, plus the problem where using a different script entry point cause the interpreter to get lost.

Simply speaking, what's the best way to avoid this kind of import errors in a clean manner? I'm not talking about anything that I can get from Pypi. There seems to be some full-stack solutions out there but I can't find details on them.

I would like to see a solution similar to many OOP languages where moving a class to another folder doesn't affect anything, like object binding.

Comment: Sorry, but **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @algerbrex Let's say whether there is one solution to this. Is it possible to keep everything still working when I place a python class to somewhere else, without editing the caller and callee? I'll rephrase the question as needed.

Comment: Have you included an `__init__.py` file in all your folders ?

Comment: Yes, even while I‘m using Python 3 I still added them. However it's a bit different here where I would like to see that you can `import foo` regardless of where foo is so `__init__.py` case doesn't apply here.

Comment: @xxbidiao your question is really unclear. Do you expect to have your `bar` module always importable as top level module as in `import bar`, even when it'll be moved somewhere else? How do you expect  Python (or dependency manager) should know where is a place it should look for `bar`?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Yes, generally so. It happened when I use some dependency injector in other language frameworks. I'm happy to have a whole file indicating where each library is (or better, let the framework figures it out) so I can have a decoupled structure.